# text-overflow floating divs inside div inside resizable div

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-resizable

Inside of a jquery resizable div I have a number of row divs, and in each row there is a left and right floated div. I would like the left floated divs to use text-overflow:ellipsis when the resizable div is smaller than the two floating divs. The right floated dive should stay the same size. I tried giving the left div a right margin, as suggested in another question, but that seems to ignore the size of the resizable div.

Here is an example of my goal:

Full size row:

```
left div       right div
```

Row resized to smaller width:

```
lef... right div
```

html:

```
<div resizable>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="floatleft">test1 hello</div>
        <div class="floatright">test2 hello</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="floatleft">test3 hello</div>
        <div class="floatright">test4 hello</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
div[resizable] {
    border: 1px solid Black;
    width: 50%;
}

.floatleft {
    float: left;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.floatright {
    float: right;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.row {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Fiddle (uses angularjs but don't worry about that):

http://jsfiddle.net/dfjrp8h5/1/

bonus points if you can explain why the floating div right margin doesn't work. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why you `float:left` left `<div>`? First in code must be right `<div>` with `float:right`. Left block must have `overflow:hidden` for clearing.

HTML:

```
<div resizable>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="floatright">test2 hello</div>
        <div class="floatleft">test1 hello</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="floatright">test4 hello</div>
        <div class="floatleft">test3 hello</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.floatleft {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.floatright {
    float: right;
    white-space: nowrap;
    margin-left:10px;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/L3cme2o9/)

`margin-right` in floating `<div>` work fine.

Comment: It looks good in the fiddle but for some reason my real code doesn't work without the float:left; the left and right divs end up on different lines. I must have some other css style applied to something that is messing it up.

Comment: Ahh, never mind, I missed that you said the right div must be first in the html. Works perfectly now, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I changed Your **CSS** a bit and it works. Just change the `CSS` in your [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dfjrp8h5/1/) with below.

```
div[resizable] {
border: 1px solid Black;
width: 50%;
}

.floatleft {
float: left;
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
width:50%;
}

.floatright {
    float: right;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width:50%;
    text-align:right;
}

.row {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: thanks, but this doesn't work so well if the left and right divs are various different sizes. Also text gets cut off from the right side of the right div when it gets smaller.